# How to call a specific function before and after every fetch api request and response

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to call a function during sending a request and after receiving response with every fetch() function using Vanilla JS.
I saw that jquery ajax is providing some kind of $.ajaxsetup for doing this but I want to do it with Vanilla JS.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to call a function after receiving a response from a fetch request?

Comment: Yes! I want to call a function when sending request and receiving response... The problem is that I've used fetch api many times. So, I want something like $.ajaxsetup thing to attach it with every fetch() function. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot do that without a custom function. The easiest way to do it would be to use Quentin's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fetch` doesn't have a feature like that. You could write a wrapper function though:

```
const myFetch = async (...args) => {
    do_before();
    const result = await fetch(...args);
    do_after();
    return result;
}
```

and then call that function instead of accessing `fetch` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by overriding the fetch function

```
// First rename original fetch function
window.originalFetch = window.fetch

// Then override fetch function with your new function
window.fetch = async (... args) => {
    console.log("before");
    // call the renamed fetch function
    const result = await window.originalFetch(...args);
    console.log("after");
    return result;
}


// Then you can use it
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

**Explanation:**

First, you change the original function name,
then you write your own function with the same name "fetch"

Thanks to [@Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) some of the code copied from his answer